# Listbox with rich options in dojo

Tags: dojo, listbox

I wonder whether there is any way to get a listbox in dojo which options are made up of an image plus a piece of text. The list should result in something like this:

listbox:
- image/icon1 + text1
- image/icon2 + text2
...
- image/iconN + textN

I've been able to do it using a drop-down list, but it isn't what I need. I must be listbox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dojo CheckedMultiSelect.

```
<select name="someName" id="someId" multiple="true" data-dojotype="dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect">
   <option id="someOptionId"><img src="images/aim-icon.gif" border=0>Blah Blah</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got to do it by doing this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <select id="list" size="3" style="width:100px;"></select>
    <input id="clear" type="button" value="Clear">
    <input id="populate" type="button" value="Populate">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dojo.js"></script>
    <script>
        dojo.addOnLoad( function(){
            dojo.connect( dojo.byId("clear"), "onclick", this, clear );
            dojo.connect( dojo.byId("populate"), "onclick", this, populate);
        });
        dojo.addOnLoad( populate );

        function populate(){
            for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
                var html = i%2 ? '<img src="image1.png"> Item ' + i :
                                 '<img src="image2.png"> Item ' + i;
                dojo.create("option", {innerHTML: html, value: i }, 'list' );
            }
            dojo.byId('populate').disabled = true;
            dojo.byId('clear').disabled = false;
        }

        function clear(){
            var list = dojo.byId("list");
            var ops = list.options;
            while( ops.length ){
                ops.remove(0);              
            }
            dojo.byId('populate').disabled = false;
            dojo.byId('clear').disabled = true;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps!